# ContentFlow Slider With Tabs For Scrolling

Tags: jquery, slider, contentflow, slidertabs

Need help to implementing tabs in contentflow slider for scrolling, simply  i want slider to scroll by tabs like

tab 1 , tab 2 , tab 3, tab 4

If user click on " tab 3" the slider 3rd image should be active, is there any way to do this with contentflow slider??

Link Of plugin :- http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/

Comment: try [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=slider+with+tab+navigation)

Comment: But I want tabs in contentflow slider i have mentioned in my questions

Comment: if you are asking about third party plugins, you should leave a link of that plugin in question.

Comment: http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/ 

This Is the link for that plugin